# List all DNS records in a domain using dig?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dig

My company runs an internal DNS for `mycompany.example`

There is a machine on the network that I need to find, but I’ve forgotten its name. If I could see a list, it would probably jog my memory.

How can I list all of the domain records for `mycompany.example`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all CNAME records for a given domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/16101/how-to-list-all-cname-records-for-a-given-domain)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322962/how-can-i-list-all-dns-records

Comment: I posted an answer at https://serverfault.com/questions/16101/how-to-list-all-cname-records-for-a-given-domain which notes that if you dig for a CNAME, e.g.,  dig +nocmd www.stackexchange.com +noall +answer you obtain verification of www being the CNAME aliasing stackexchange.com

Comment: @OrangeDog Beware of this, now we have CNAME centric answers here.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

## Answer

The short answer to your specific question of listing CNAMEs is that you cannot without permission to do zone transfers (see [How to list all CNAME records for a given domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/16101/how-to-list-all-cname-records-for-a-given-domain)).

That said, if your company's DNS server still supports the ANY query, you can use dig to list the other records by doing:

```
dig +noall +answer +multiline yourdomain.yourtld any
```

These ... `+noall +answer +multiline` ... are strictly optional and are simply output formatting flags to make the output more easily human readable (see [dig man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig)).

## Example

```
$ dig +noall +answer +multiline bad.horse any
```

Returns:

```
bad.horse.              7200 IN A 162.252.205.157
bad.horse.              7200 IN CAA 0 issue "letsencrypt.org"
bad.horse.              7200 IN CAA 0 iodef "mailto:abuse@sandwich.net"
bad.horse.              7200 IN MX 10 mx.sandwich.net.
bad.horse.              7200 IN NS a.sn1.us.
bad.horse.              7200 IN NS b.sn1.us.
bad.horse.              7200 IN SOA a.sn1.us. n.sn1.us. (
                                2017032202 ; serial
                                1200       ; refresh (20 minutes)
                                180        ; retry (3 minutes)
                                1209600    ; expire (2 weeks)
                                60         ; minimum (1 minute)
                                )
```

## Caveats (RFC8482)

Note that, [since around 2019](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8482), most public DNS servers have stopped answering most DNS `ANY` queries usefully. For background on that, see: [RFC8482 - Saying goodbye to ANY](https://blog.cloudflare.com/rfc8482-saying-goodbye-to-any/)

If `ANY` queries do not enumerate multiple records, the only option is to request each [record type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) (e.g. A, CNAME, or MX) individually.

Comment: any is no good on some DNS servers ```IN HINFO "ANY obsoleted" "See draft-ietf-dnsop-refuse-any"```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with `CNAME` records...

Comment: for me, `dig @8.8.8.8 +nocmd yourdomain.example any +multiline +noall +answer` lists more records

Comment: This command returns 0 answer records on any of 8 domains I tried.

Comment: dig domain.com ANY is a much more clear and expressive answer.

Comment: Since `ANY` queries are no longer honored by most DNS servers, it's much simpler to use an online tool like https://nslookup.io, which will query every record type individually and display all the DNS records in one overview.

Comment: Note: Most DNS servers no longer support (since about 2019) the ANY query. This is because it was difficult to maintain and prone to abuse. There's some good background here: https://blog.cloudflare.com/rfc8482-saying-goodbye-to-any/

The alternative is to query specifically for the records types you are interested in.

Comment: Even if `ANY` worked, and still now, there is a wrong assumption under it. For some reasons people equate it with `ALL` which is not true at all: if you send an `ANY` request to a recursive nameserver it will reply with all records it has in its cache, and only that, so not necessarily (and almost never) all records that exist at the authoritative nameserver, which one is free to ignore `ANY` requests completely anyway. So this `ANY = ALL` myth should be debunked and `ANY` should die and disappear from everywhere, it never worked as people considered it should work.

Answer (score 103):

A much easier command to remember (and more informative) is:

```
> dig google.com ANY
```

Which returns the following:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> google.com ANY
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31013
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 22, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     17  IN  A   74.125.225.72
google.com.     17  IN  A   74.125.225.73
google.com.     17  IN  A   74.125.225.78
google.com.     17  IN  A   74.125.225.64
google.com.     17  IN  A   74.125.225.65
google.com.     17  IN  A   74.125.225.66
google.com.     17  IN  A   74.125.225.67
google.com.     17  IN  A   74.125.225.68
google.com.     17  IN  A   74.125.225.69
google.com.     17  IN  A   74.125.225.70
google.com.     17  IN  A   74.125.225.71
google.com.     86400   IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     86400   IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
google.com.     86400   IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
google.com.     86400   IN  NS  ns4.google.com.
google.com.     66641   IN  SOA ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com.    2013082900 7200 1800 1209600 300
google.com.     177 IN  MX  40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     177 IN  MX  50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     177 IN  MX  10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     177 IN  MX  20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     177 IN  MX  30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     287 IN  AAAA    2607:f8b0:4009:803::1007

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.google.com.     3924    IN  A   216.239.32.10
ns2.google.com.     64508   IN  A   216.239.34.10
ns3.google.com.     64508   IN  A   216.239.36.10

;; Query time: 77 msec
;; SERVER: 10.6.23.4#53(10.6.23.4)
;; WHEN: Fri Sep 13 14:26:09 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 506
```

Comment: This is not what the question is asking for.  It's asking for all of the records within the 'google.com.' domain, not just the records for 'google.com.'.  There is nothing in your query listing anything not 'google.com.' except for the glue records (A records for the name servers).

Comment: Perfect command.  Succinct and easy to remember, thanks for posting!

Comment: Now the only answer from `google.com` to `ANY` queries is: `google.com.  14400 IN CNAME forcesafesearch.google.com.` (https://gist.github.com/Dorian/afb136672c91fc89df572a4b0f8106dd)

Comment: The [IETF proposes to refuse ANY](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-dnsop-refuse-any-02). I get: `HINFO   "Please stop asking for ANY" "See draft-ietf-dnsop-refuse-any"`

Comment: The proposal to refuse `ANY` requests is now [RFC 8482](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8482).

Answer (score 67):

Try:

```
dig @ns.example.com -tAXFR example.com
```

This may or may not work. Many DNS servers will deny a [DNS Zone Transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_zone_transfer) like this. For more information, see [How the AXFR protocol works](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/axfr-notes.html)

Comment: You're on the right track, but that syntax doesn't work for me.  What works is `dig @ns.example.com -tAXFR example.com` where ns.example.com is a primary nameserver for the zone, and where the DNS admin has enabled zone transfer requests from the host or IP you're querying from.  Without AXFR permission there is no way to query ALL DNS records in a zone.  I'm not sure, but I don't believe AXFR requests can be done recursively, hence the need to query the zone's top-level nameserver directly, which is what the `@ns.example.com` part of the syntax does.  The actual hostname will vary.

Comment: Yes @Jim you’re right, you may need to specify an authoritative nameserver to query.

Answer (score 29):

You can also use `host` DNS lookup utility with `-l` switch:

```
host -l example.com
```

Of course you need DNS zone transfer rights for this to work.

Comment: same as dig -t AXFR domain.name

Comment: @XXL ... except a lot easier to remember.... +1

Answer (score 4):

```
dig domain ANY
```

should give you all records. I write should because it depends on the DNS-Server used.
dig gmx.de ANY with my Telekom-DNS DNS-Servers 217.237.148.102 17.237.151.115 and  only gives

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
gmx.de.                 65970   IN      DS      26497 8 2 E7A00568AC320816600195F536B6BF2EEB06B0B2728146536FA53B22 45DDA66D
gmx.de.                 65970   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 2 86400 20190812150105 20190805150105 47740 de. iKcp0dWmv1o/p4e31njqplr7noJE98ZEMfzjnSZ3XLqGvtSX8gVTBLVI yId8uMLvN/9NkRfzxELFiO9K3+x95lJnPrE0VpZoaGFpjYNIUOQhq7Xb tvWEXYH8y7XUw+VkSIJa3DQS7P/cNFGJ1/BinKIYtDn46PPNtdxFB+Tp Ee8=
```

Whereas dig gmx.de MX gives

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
gmx.de.                 474     IN      MX      10 mx00.emig.gmx.net.
gmx.de.                 474     IN      MX      10 mx01.emig.gmx.net.
```

use dig gmx.de ANY @8.8.8.8 to query Google DNS and you get a long list.

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
gmx.de.                 23      IN      A       82.165.229.87
gmx.de.                 23      IN      A       82.165.230.36
gmx.de.                 23      IN      RRSIG   A 8 2 30 20190818065308 20190804065308 43065 gmx.de. Uh+KdZt/0mpk1JCjUmLFVHNaNnlv8zNRAc7ME0b9D/ULGHPmO6Ate9nG vFhcBC2c2ktJuqEw5pNieIVMLmkj9v7yzmccK0f1PwGgoW6IkuHxYVuN ExrWBpb0bHubF6xjMi8h3+JUd+kOEQdBX8XRAcVaxE9NTHkgqrFaZXjt NsICB0Hjq+LP7GfYTrRkaKsW9je5X6sfuBDDCtrc7MFJIm94Cm8mwD2d nVxD+1Bye+EXUbUjnaqjmJjXviK1GSaSRqiCcNd8TjBisBRQoKloxam9 NCikIMMEO5fAtAALtogxUtB3Znln0bKj7gTrOH21c5qC8LFyr7eVZoEN X9QXVQ==
gmx.de.                 21593   IN      NS      ns-gmx.ui-dns.de.
gmx.de.                 21593   IN      NS      ns-gmx.ui-dns.biz.
gmx.de.                 21593   IN      NS      ns-gmx.ui-dns.com.
gmx.de.                 21593   IN      NS      ns-gmx.ui-dns.org.
gmx.de.                 21593   IN      RRSIG   NS 8 2 86400 20190818065308 20190804065308 43065 gmx.de. xY3gZxt47huiUseFZsbj4026RqGDZBuUCY9tv2CQmmpGUIH+YQLmQFKV xzZBS9MTnOIr2s4MMUbav7O/IaaCFlXb44gv4lCbjtSABQWF92rVZ1Js 89clPvLN5LUyzwBuEyx9Ew1dVvRGyJhG0icPPa6iFmpQvSLqwEEhck/H jOkFI99rWfM+gQRcYVvONlN5PP2idWOzeJpmg+BeSNDCTvtqFqMd+adS +uqooQarjcu6w3nGcOCnbdp//Ie2oXwXrVDDD3ntgJqktc4ggTaDoBnX Fbq2LXNejmHmM0VhmPRAAHGRyhjaaIVso8rqETz8fHTDNiS1k20mdF62 JyalPQ==
gmx.de.                 21593   IN      SOA     ns-gmx.ui-dns.org. dnsadmin.1und1.de. 2013084217 28800 7200 604800 600
gmx.de.                 21593   IN      RRSIG   SOA 8 2 86400 20190818065308 20190804065308 43065 gmx.de. C4Rhhfennofs0+Si8LyTs9FlMDXzaExKK60jFNvusx8ti06Vj7WPPXm8 +lc69v0AKGXzjnBqdR/Th8cTOC3eTwT/vJvV9k/UVJfN9/e8ASOjKY0P mHbBgH0VRqU1nHYOzVzuJkO2UIrZdMxIZYQ1gXmYK/4L2QL+iGUhTTJX /GKQKxRGi2YzgohpBx7Jtl3kYCcUudSq0zz3t2C7W6K6AKZC4B8cjOZU t+U678I1TRerLAzlaDmP2NbNrBhdG9CpUio4mW50X+59u2H4/NaGZ4Gm +LmeqLa6o88N6hutILfmyBLZGWD+j7mzDTjdXD2dvuIpjrQsHznvL7ZT ltQb4g==
gmx.de.                 893     IN      MX      10 mx00.emig.gmx.net.
gmx.de.                 893     IN      MX      10 mx01.emig.gmx.net.
gmx.de.                 893     IN      RRSIG   MX 8 2 900 20190818065308 20190804065308 43065 gmx.de. g9qdLpwVTbLxaTa3CfSOTEZfUZWEf5RwCjaiquSpTQYgYEe+zDiGtd7I CnCQIgBVJIZUTBsXCbuPdd0qZzmGe8W2z9j/cz3WbQyf9ZIJrxZPDzV/ tnpB3j+GKmHkbuYg9CRw1ILpDBnvw6syV/z03nlH99eXWAee9b7S1Muk fIf6Xwt41hqyAof144jM/6GSaKfe4T1Rgc07i9LneHdt9n/C60Jo4aj9 bJ2Hdg9W1Fnd9aPg8xTt6Q+Ahz4kUR2hQSmwHLZnq36pIhkJkqxV+YPu etFtfERwyVW1eDPmG68tXqo4clBmtIzF0HqgxB0cdn8SgdlXs9lFqTgT 8RK+Rg==
gmx.de.                 293     IN      TXT     "v=spf1 redirect=gmx.net"
gmx.de.                 293     IN      TXT     "google-site-verification=8jV5RCya962H1ur14xR3xWCFUBsExt_YibC3HkuJ9X8"
gmx.de.                 293     IN      TXT     "_telesec-domain-validation=D0B26BF4EFFDD17671E1967D1CC7F1DA06B99F496A3C52F2A7F81E7A70F463FD"
gmx.de.                 293     IN      RRSIG   TXT 8 2 300 20190818065308 20190804065308 43065 gmx.de. tyRidjkmugwBfjjxcZgwXJk9ny/tEUD0unfvDUc0w8L7iG/QgXI5BnvO 0wU7EcwmJLkEyWUDu88KGiFK/HByW6oNpenz+1ZKD1uFKCOXccMClEHQ tbDDOkMmCCLzk17Jnz06oyhAVv50vNChtaCjKTz/+9IQi8LHyIi3KqNO C0doOvaaWjbF+C3Y7HZD7+PNjBXNmnvPjrTpxDsShcrVLYm6n38tNerk nZCD6gtFVnsSNy/zG2Ro+bma5oQMCkRPTUtWeVuIC/VitIYizVVqK3DO eDRyRpTe9HaFXXV0614GgxVjimbgsRXG2BcVz+M7410lIs4hjZkpE2+N YxAwsw==
gmx.de.                 593     IN      DNSKEY  256 3 8 AwEAAexRGtsaOHA3h7MCVG0AACIOr9DBpSNjh2N+kti0GYM448B6fyCS UGjA5VKzUq6szDQ4RDgJamDw/0pCWzFEjfKqD4glnyKzyALpkngznkDa 7I9kJo9gLt9BztCvthaMRHNfgDm2Rchfn8ahaPJXcHXMAPAuJmLYPdyd Pa21etNBCgEgmdLWNrY91FeSD40It1wqaw3i8O6yBgmRMz8JZV7kk3dH 2ocaS6WfgpAj+JzyG6CcPurv7zkq5/FQMOjF9vfNjtOhLAFDrm3fe4nW pcD9Gq864myFWDB1hcVjfRZ0370gjuZ5PxLyqlMVdpbKkkPX8L+p0iiM cHlGSKaoBJs=
gmx.de.                 593     IN      DNSKEY  257 3 8 AwEAAadAbK9K4yEQ6DC0jQMWYZH008gPUmBT7xIHPUIezY2/PGj5VTZy zNzpS+02jxaR86jmSo6d9zfpITwlLX730NwKP80D3Tpqu9W4h7x7/P+A ue8vjiqp148y2Ei/PG8/ePHs8C2QAUDMuKDGzffj/Rtji3rirT2p7/Vj vUByaT2+T9zzsenOyKJdULv6uZDUs5vkYBPRUWOXARKGII5sf2qrAo2P tr8bpynJE7CJHNg+UUGwb9ZpQ6lxBvKiFsPDB6kmYzUglfxpknyjs4bH vFsty1O7m6/cGRP+Vkz1vDhPBzENUvULegmMSQc/pzUNfI/LzzJiEu7R ZxP4Djcop/8=
gmx.de.                 593     IN      RRSIG   DNSKEY 8 2 600 20190818065308 20190804065308 26497 gmx.de. H2/TQzTV+UEQbe9gqM5SIP/BtcoGrhNnkzwB3mVtFJwLfr2xMrv9HQT5 xKSVLLobjIUxoKq29qPKJ6OIzEMZY72Kcrd1xJ91U/e1aVLjxdUa67Wj ZCcsCxBx/xOWiFDmv6+8qxTmoFeHBg7BD92nRJLXqrzO7jHlIFstfvrJ U31YvlxY9e6o4WqSH3VoDHB8rmN52N6EMbGVwzhZRI2PGsaYv5eeibDp zbqAqJ//O+BIhS5jkdvXbV02erLApjzxe8sXTvAZpmgbH+DNmG8DTBZs 2oU3v+rsgFlwxp22d176mwQoVUWYof8xwEYGMgMuMM32nCu/iqsaW428 Fk5YiA==
gmx.de.                 593     IN      NSEC3PARAM 1 0 24 53DB50B23808A4C2
gmx.de.                 593     IN      RRSIG   NSEC3PARAM 8 2 86400 20190818065308 20190804065308 43065 gmx.de. fnR7VcUl37Nw26t+ZmbwHmjLm/znrBjZkPCVRW6ca25FtAUeOAJ3tdVy faPy0KHf87sfD8NVu134tLC4pd2NP5ELkQZM5jEhpVJF55Og6y1pFSFK +6TFPvXbw93SW3ZhTJOHhU9D/suPvvAfyYtQDvzE7WtHN/u/XfGK9F8/ BJzTUACwer+y7fk8xuUjmOa29Y4oH6/g/AZNkOuvsWZ1npH/StHxOAtM EI0g/XTDJ4w5rji8cdGVcBzhNOfUFhaInVLgeFm6PXd9gXtnzbrkC2ha 3vBT3S4wYEM8YEW6H1A8zHcNS6eA1cuCTHfGPaU1dqoZ4ujOIE05C/YQ YgWOfg==
gmx.de.                 21593   IN      CAA     0 issue "Digicert.com"
gmx.de.                 21593   IN      CAA     0 issue "telesec.de"
gmx.de.                 21593   IN      RRSIG   CAA 8 2 86400 20190818065308 20190804065308 43065 gmx.de. TG3BUmiwib0qvBQ127aIAG89SwdD46UuBy0wK1ohOc0xoP36fSh3g30G PUU7OGBCgaCapwzxCON+gGY7xCkD37cZt8ydzBCxFGvWyf0PvObicgrY /DjLuWOOJLJjNv8Ab3mg+vVD0Dki4ZEodrKU9pv8B204afee2OQFFXs7 bfDJrllvqQ8mX8nd6ou5+21+cwldF/uRP/t4GM0qIf1fajZsgmqoHQ8t ARzBWlZix4SlpKoOyvGjjHGnpCTsOWHlWB1UU/SUnmPIGh1dDq/Go+PN z7zT2khWQy2xYJPd4Cg/HHzfBT1CvTg3C25ncj/BEHCcbHnjMNx2vtms OCwyog==
```

However using QuadNine dig gmx.de ANY @9.9.9.9 we only get

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
gmx.de.                 22680   IN      DS      26497 8 2 E7A00568AC320816600195F536B6BF2EEB06B0B2728146536FA53B22 45DDA66D
gmx.de.                 22680   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 2 86400 20190812150105 20190805150105 47740 de. iKcp0dWmv1o/p4e31njqplr7noJE98ZEMfzjnSZ3XLqGvtSX8gVTBLVI yId8uMLvN/9NkRfzxELFiO9K3+x95lJnPrE0VpZoaGFpjYNIUOQhq7Xb tvWEXYH8y7XUw+VkSIJa3DQS7P/cNFGJ1/BinKIYtDn46PPNtdxFB+Tp Ee8=
```

So try different DNS-Servers to really get all DNS-Records or query for specific records directly.

Comment: The `@8.8.8.8` was the thing I was missing from other answers.  Thanks!

Comment: This is the best answer. Good number of DNS servers do not support ANY any more.

Comment: Again, this doesn't list all records within the zone (e.g. `something.gmx.de`), just all records regardless of type for `gmx.de` itself.

Answer (score 3):

The approach you're trying to use won't work. See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/119023/get-all-dns-records-on-remote-server) for more information. Assuming you're the admin (if you're not please discuss this with your admin and read the FAQ before posting again) simply look up the zone file.

Answer (score 2):

```
dnscmd <ServerName> /zoneprint <Domain>
```

I found none of the answers so far would work for me, mostly due to zone transfer failures.  This command did not run into that issue and presented me with something closer to what I get in the DNS Manager tool.

Comment: For me this is the best answer.  No zone transfer issues, just pipe it to `find` and you're done.  All domain records referencing the server you're interested in.  (note `ServerName` above is the DNS server).

Comment: weird, could not `brew install dnscmd`

Comment: dnscmd is windows only: see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784399(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to accomplish, you can likely obtain a large list of subdomains from a different technique not directly related to DNS, but rather use certificate transparency. Services such as crt.sh can do so. E.g.

https://crt.sh/?q=stackoverflow.com

Read more on certificate transparency here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_Transparency

Comment: Cute workaround! Note that often organisations wil have an internal CA and use that for issuing certificates with their internal domain name and those won't show up in the certificate transparency system.  When they do use a public CA for certificates on internal hosts you might still run into the following https://crt.sh limit  *"Sorry, your search results have been truncated.
It is not currently possible to sort and paginate large result sets efficiently, so only a random subset is shown below."* and will still get an incomplete view.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/

Here you can check up any domain online very easy

Im not affiliated with any of the above, just putting it our there to help like minded professionals.

Comment: Since this is an internal DNS, how would the external tool find the records?

Answer (score -1):

Using dig to see all records, first you need to know -  DNS server where domain parking

(example for external dns)# dig @8.8.8.8 google.com ANY

(example for local dns) # dig @192.168.0.1 example.com ANY

Comment: this answer is a duplicate of the once above?! Any new suggestions either?

Answer (score -2):

You can also use nslookup tool:

```
nslookup example.com
```

Comment: It just gives you the IP address behind a specific domain or subdomain.

Answer (score -7):

I ended up using nmap to scan the network.

For example:

```
nmap -v -sP 192.16.0.0/16
```

Comment: That's a good solution to your problem but not a great answer to the question "List all DNS records in a domain using dig?". You might want to edit your question and change the title.

Comment: nmaping a /16 will generate 256^2 (65536) DNS lookups. I bet your DNS admins love you.

Comment: @markdrayton, although the scan will send out 2^16 ping requests (~50Mb of raw data, filtered out by most network interfaces), it will only perform reverse-DNS lookups for the hosts that are online.