# Why doesn't `dig` show records?

Tags: domain-name-system, dig

Every time I use `dig` I get a vague feeling that I'm not really sure whether it's giving me correct data.

Now I've used it like this:

```
# dig socialimpactportfolio.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> socialimpactportfolio.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 35289
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;socialimpactportfolio.com.     IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
socialimpactportfolio.com. 1799 IN      SOA     dns1.name-services.com. info.name-services.com. 2002050701 10800 3600 604800 3600

;; Query time: 121 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu May 22 14:01:03 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 103
```

As you can see, there is no `ANSWER` section, despite the fact that there's a working website on that domain.

Why?

I'd really like a program that simply shows all the DNS records in the most non-confusing manner.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your query is incorrect, or to put it differently - no, there is no entry for `socialimpactportfolio.com`. Dig is telling you about the problem.

The domain works in the browser, because it will helpfully try and add the `www.` prefix, and lo and behold:

```
dig www.socialimpactportfolio.com
...
www.socialimpactportfolio.com. 1783 IN  CNAME   kochi-9186.herokussl.com.
```

If you are looking for a tool that will somehow show you the complete zone - I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by a "complete zone"?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/138949/list-all-dns-records-in-a-domain-using-dig

Answer (score 5):

Getting `NOERROR` and yet no `ANSWER SECTION` is telling you that the domain name does exist, but has no records of the specified type. In fact a domain name can exist without having any records at all, and that is different from returning `NXDOMAIN`, though in many cases applications will treat them the same.

In both cases a `SOA` record is included such that the client will know how long that answer may be cached.

A domain with no records at all can have subdomains, which do have records.

Answer (score 3):

I just checked, that domain doesn't have an A record, so your dig output is correct. The website is located under ***www.***.socialimpactportfolio.com, i.e. www.socialimpactportfolio.com, which again points (two chained CNAMEs) to amazonaws.com.

Answer (score 1):

It says it all in the dig output:

```
status: NOERROR
QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1
```

No errors, you did 1 query, there were no answers, the response was from an authoritative nameserver.

---

If you search for all records for that zone, you will find more information:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> nslookup -type=all socialimpactportfolio.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  fe80::1

Non-authoritative answer:
socialimpactportfolio.com       MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = eforwardct2.name-services.com
socialimpactportfolio.com       MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = eforwardct3.name-services.com
socialimpactportfolio.com       MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = eforwardct.name-services.com
socialimpactportfolio.com
        primary name server = dns1.name-services.com
        responsible mail addr = info.name-services.com
        serial  = 2002050701
        refresh = 10800 (3 hours)
        retry   = 3600 (1 hour)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)
socialimpactportfolio.com       nameserver = dns4.name-services.com
socialimpactportfolio.com       nameserver = dns3.name-services.com
socialimpactportfolio.com       nameserver = dns2.name-services.com
socialimpactportfolio.com       nameserver = dns1.name-services.com
socialimpactportfolio.com       nameserver = dns5.name-services.com

socialimpactportfolio.com       nameserver = dns5.name-services.com
socialimpactportfolio.com       nameserver = dns4.name-services.com
socialimpactportfolio.com       nameserver = dns3.name-services.com
socialimpactportfolio.com       nameserver = dns2.name-services.com
socialimpactportfolio.com       nameserver = dns1.name-services.com
dns1.name-services.com  internet address = 98.124.192.1
dns2.name-services.com  internet address = 98.124.197.1
dns3.name-services.com  internet address = 98.124.193.1
dns4.name-services.com  internet address = 98.124.194.1
dns5.name-services.com  internet address = 98.124.196.1
```